# R ODBC connection failed when I upgrade to R version 3.5.2

Tags: r, oracle, rodbc

When I was using R 3.4.0 (64bit), the following code worked perfectly well.

```
#R Connect to Oracle DB
library(RODBC)
#Open connection
con <- odbcConnect(dsn = "DBNAME", uid="myuserid", pwd="mypassword",rows_at_time=500)
```

However I recently updated to R 3.5.2 (64bit), and now I cannot connect anymore.

I get the following error message when I try

> Warning messages: 1: In
>   RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=DBNAME;UID=myuserid;PWD=mypassword",
>   :   [RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message
>   [Microsoft][Gestionnaire de pilotes ODBC] Source de données
>   introuvable et nom de pilote non spécifié 2: In
>   RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=DBNAME;UID=myuserid;PWD=mypassword",
>   :   ODBC connection failed

Any help on resolving this issue will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try updating package: `install.packages("RODBC")`.

Comment: Tried that. No luck

Comment: Did anything else happen with R update such as an OS upgrade (Win 7 to Win 10)? Did you move over DSN file to new or rebuilt machine?

Comment: No. Funny thing is when I switch projects in RStudio and run the same code it works.

Comment: What happens if you use a connection string instead? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28941648 - And: Are you sure the DSN name is correct and works (try it in the ODBC Manager)?