# Reading access ..accdb file using R

Tags: r, rodbc

i try to read access .accdb file using R with package RODBC.

```
library(RODBC)
db<-file.path("D:/file.accdb") 
channel<-odbcConnectAccess2007(db)
```

I got an error message :

```
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect(con, ...) :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
2: In odbcDriverConnect(con, ...) : ODBC connection failed
```

What is my problem?
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failure to connect to odbc database in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17069231/failure-to-connect-to-odbc-database-in-r)

Comment: No, i read a file and not connect to database. I use 64-bit